# Ein Kamocha on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, time, torah-service

Before the Ark is opened on Shabbat, we don't just say "veyahi b'n'so'a ha'aron" as we would on a weekday. We begin with Ein Kamocha. The Artscroll siddur (I don't have the page number handy) explains that we do this on Shabbat because we have more time for davening than we do on a weekday.

If this is the case, then why don't we also do it at mincha on Shabbat?

Is there a different reason to explain the addition in Shacharit that would explain excluding it during mincha?

Comment: We don’t have as much time at mincha. We have to finish before sh’kiah in order to make hamotzi and eat Seuda Shlishit.

Comment: @LoAni if you start too late and haven't eaten yet sure, but the point is we could schedule Mincha earlier because no one is at work. That's the whole question: why start late?

Comment: Consider Megillah 22b

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Megillah.21a.11.2?lang=he

Comment: @JoelK But on the other hand https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.26b.15

Comment: Does the Artscroll give a source. Perhaps that source answers your question.

Comment: "having more time" doesn't sound like the greatest reason to me. I think there may be something else, here. As for Shabbat mincha. this may have something to do with the reason for having Torah reading at that time. It was a later addition to accomodate the *yoshvei kranot* (merchants) who wouldn't have time to attend a weekday market reading. Also, Shabbat afternoon really does not leave much extra time as Seudah Shlishit is considered important. See a discussion on that concept of even studying Torah after Mincha Shabbat.

Comment: @GershonGold I don't recall that it did but I will check again tomorrow.

Comment: BTW: There are communities - e.g. (some?) Yekkes - who never say it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is because the reading of Mincha on Shabbat wasn't instituted lichvod Shabbat, but for other reasons. R' Aharon David in V'ed Ya'aleh brings a couple of reasons:

1. For יושבי קרנות - he interprets this to mean that these do-nothings won't be bored ([pg. 78](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=78&book=53644)).
2. For shopkeepers who can't hear the reading on Mondays and Thursdays ([pg. 83](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=83&book=53644)) - this is per [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Kamma.82a.4?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Bava_Kamma.82a.4.1&lang2=bi) (and others, such as the Rosh) on Bava Kamma 82a.

While the origin of the minhag of saying Ein Kamocha on Shabbat comes from the Shibolei Haleket's father:

> "אבא מרי ר' אברהם זצ"ל הנהיג לומר בכל שבת ויום טוב כשמוציאין ספר תורה לקרות בו פסוקין שלשבחות: אין כמוך  באלהים ה', מלכותך מלכות כל עולמים, שמע ישראל, וכול' כסדר הכתוב בסידורים בשלושה רגלים עד יגדיל תורה ויאדיר..." ([Shibolei Haleket, siman 77](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8919&pgnum=99))

Translation: "My father, my teacher, R' Avraham zt"l instituted the custom of saying every Shabbat and Yom Tov that when taking out the Torah to read, they must read upon it verses of exaltation: "Ein Kamocha ba'Elokim Hashem, Malchtcha Malchut Kol Olamim, Shema Yisrael, etc, in the order that's written in the siddurs for the three festivals until Yagdil Torah V'Yadir..."

And Rabbi David explains that in his understanding, the Shibolei Haleket's father instituted saying Ein Kamocha also on Shabbat and other Yamim Tovim because he thought that that's how the minhag used to be ([pg. 39](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=39&book=53644)).